# Accessing AWS DocumentDB from different VPC in a another account using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-documentdb

I have a lambda function in one account (lets say Account A) which is trying to access AWS Document DB inside VPC (private) which is in another account (Account B)

I see that latest [DocumentDB documentation] (https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/faqs/) mentions that VPC peering supports accessing the DocumentDB cluster outside VPC, does this cover VPC in other account ?

**Is it possible to use VPC peering to access DocumentDB inside a VPC (in Account B) in lambda which is another VPC in Account A ?**

Comment: I don't see a reason why. You can establish VPC peering across accounts. Then I think, a lambda would need to be [set to access resources](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/) in Account A.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, the lambda runs inside it’s own vpc which is governed by aws, is it possible to still do vpc peering ?

Answer (score 1):

Sagar, As you described, this is possible with VPC peering. Let's say you have a DocumentDB cluster in VPC A and a lambda function in VPC B. Your lambda function can access your DocumentDB cluster if you setup VPC peering between VPC A and VPC B.

Check out this Twitch talk (https://www.twitch.tv/videos/510542149) at 46:14. I am working on a tutorial that covers some aspects of this, iil share it here when I have it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to perform vpc peering and it worked just fine.